# OneSignal causing Google Play Services version to change

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, onesignal

I'm trying to integrate OneSignal into my project, but it's causing errors with Google Play Services.

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

dependencies {
    ...

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:15.0.1"

    ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now, I added OneSignal.

```
buildscript {
    ...

    dependencies {
        ...

        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.8.1'

        ...
    }
}
```

And here is my updated `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

dependencies {
    ...

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:15.0.1"

    ...

    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1'

    ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now, syncing with this will cause errors:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0
...

Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.3.0
...

Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.3.0
...
```

For some reason adding OneSignal causes Google Play Services to be bumped up to to my `firebase-messaging` version ( 17.3.0 )

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using version range and replace this in project level gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.11.0, 0.99.99]'
    }
```

and this in app level gradle dependencies

```
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
```

and moreover you are missong with oneSignal ID (idea from your current posted gradle)
add that too [check here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup)

once you are done with syn do clean and rebuild project option

Comment: Adding a range seemed to have fixed the issue. Do you know why using a range for OneSignal is better? And I have my ID in the build.gradle, I just omitted it from the question for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be also using the latest version of the Google Play services plugin in your top-level build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Comment: Hi Doug, I was using `com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1` before, but I've just tried with `4.1.0`, still the same issue.

Comment: Android Studio did not hint for an updated version there, as it usually does.

Comment: I updated my question, it seems to be an issue with adding `OneSignal`.

Answer (score 0):

One Signal internally handle the dependency of firebase. Why do you use firebase dependency in your app gradle? Remove them and rebuild.

Remove them

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0"
```

Comment: I wasn't aware it used Firebase, that makes more sense. But I don't want OneSignal controlling my firebase version.

Comment: I tried removing Firebase as you suggested, but I get another error. "Android dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:15.0.0' is set to compileOnly/provided which is not supported"

Comment: No, I don't use `firebase-measurement` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use latest version of firebase dependencies like this,

```
 com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1
com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0
```

Try this.

Answer (score -3):

Try to add google repository

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    ...
}
```